# Function runs in terminal, but wont work in .sh script

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-functions

I am trying to use Bash commands for completion, just to complete some commands that are used for my main .sh file. But I am having some problems with this Bash code:

```
function _test()
{
  local cur
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W '--activate --help --new' -- $cur ) )
}
complete -F _test test
```

now the code works fine when I drop it in terminal and call it, but does nothing if I put it in my .sh scrip and run it. I also tried to copy&paste this function into bashrc file (that does not work neither), because I am new to Bash scripting and I don't know what is wrong. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: What is the first line of your main `.sh` script? Is it `#!/bin/sh` ?

Comment: Then, your `.sh` files are being run by `/bin/sh`, which might be (or not) `bash`. Could you post the output of `type sh` and of `sh -c 'echo "Running bash version=$BASH_VERSION"'`.

Comment: Are you running it? Or sourcing it? You need to source it.

Comment: I am sourcing it.

Answer (score 1):

Just dropped your code into my `.bashrc` and it does work.

You should execute it to make it take effect after putting it in to `.bashrc` by running `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` or just opening a new terminal.

It wouldn't work if you run the .sh script containing that completion codes by using `bash XXX.sh` or `./XXX.sh`. Use `. ./XXX.sh` or `source ./XXX.sh` instead.